# Behavior tree for robotics applications

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm writing a behavior tree (BT) for my robot which will wait for mode choosing and proceed the chosen mode. Here I use a Sequence node, the first child node will wait for a service call to /choose_mode service and then output the mode, the second child node is Switch node and will take the output as input, then proceed the corresponding mode.
Is there a standard BT structure for this case, and can you guys suggest documents about BT for robotics applications?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397700/behavior-tree-for-robotics-applications/) by [Kevin1719](https://answers.ros.org/users/86013/kevin1719/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2022-03-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) on 2022-03-18**:
The navigation stack of ROS2 works around BT. https://navigation.ros.org/behavior_trees/index.html

**Comment by [Kevin1719](https://answers.ros.org/users/86013/kevin1719/) on 2022-03-18**:
Thanks for your reply, but I'm currently working with ROS1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am Davide, the author of BehaviorTree.CPP
You are doing it right, in my opinion.

---

Originally posted by [Davide Faconti](https://answers.ros.org/users/578/davide-faconti/) with karma: 308 on 2022-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin1719](https://answers.ros.org/users/86013/kevin1719/) on 2022-03-18**:
Thank you Davide.